# Lewis dot structure of beryllium fluoride

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, lewis-structure

I'm so confused because I'm trying to draw $\ce{BeF2}$ … and the way it's drawn (something like $\ce{F-Be-F}$) just doesn't make sense to me because Be can only hold 2 valence electrons. But this structure shows it having 4.

Comment: It doesn’t exactly have four valence electrons the way you drew it, unless you assume the oxygen of water to hold eight valence electrons.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. $\ce{BeF2}$ is [octet deficient](https://www.nyu.edu/classes/tuckerman/adv.chem/lectures/lecture_11/node7.html).

To solve this problem, they would form [polymers](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/BeCl2.png) by themselves, but that would be out of syllabus.

(I cannot find the polymer of $\ce{BeF2}$, so here is the polymer of $\ce{BeCl2}$:)

[image]